# Converting String with PM and AM to Timestamp Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I recognize there are a bunch of posts related to this question, but I have yet to figure this out.I have a STRING field with the following Unix timestamp values:

```
Feb 27, 2021 14:11:25 PM    
Dec 07, 2020 04:48:44 AM    
Dec 07, 2020 04:48:35 AM    
Dec 07, 2020 04:48:55 AM    
Dec 07, 2020 04:51:51 AM
```

I am not sure why this field has PM and AM, but I need to work around it.

I'd like to convert this field to a TIMESTAMP in a BigQuery table. I have tried a few approaches:

```
    MIN(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y %H:%i:%s', REPLACE(REPLACE(messagecreatedat, ' AM', ''), ' PM', ''))) AS min_messagecreatedat,
```

and

```
MIN(
  COALESCE(
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p', messagecreatedat),
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S', messagecreatedat)
  )
) AS min_messagecreatedat,
```

Both do not work. I get the error

> Failed to parse input string "Mar 16, 2021 22:17:27"

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me

```
 MIN(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y %T %p', messagecreatedat, 'UTC')) AS min_messagecreatedat,
```

Answer (score 0):

See below example (BigQuery Standard SQL) with two oaches to address your issue

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT 'Feb 27, 2021 14:11:25 PM' AS messagecreatedat UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dec 07, 2020 04:48:44 AM' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dec 07, 2020 04:48:35 AM' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dec 07, 2020 04:48:55 AM' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mar 16, 2021 22:17:27' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dec 07, 2020 04:51:51 AM' 
)
SELECT 
  messagecreatedat, 
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y %T', REGEXP_REPLACE(messagecreatedat, ' [AP]M$', ''), 'UTC') AS messagecreatedat_1, 
  IFNULL(
    SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y %T %p', messagecreatedat, 'UTC'),
    SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y %T', messagecreatedat, 'UTC')
  ) messagecreatedat_2
FROM your_table
```

with output

[image]